# Failover cluster wouldn't fail over

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, failovercluster

I have an active-passive failover cluster on 2008r2 with SQL server 2008 clustered on it.

I go to fail it over for maintenance and the resource failed to come online on either node.  Once I rebooted the passive node, I was able to bring it online again on the original active node.  Once the second node came back up I was able to successfully fail over to that node and carry on with my updates.

One clue was the LAN network resource was suddenly failed for the cluster.  I do have it set to allow cluster network communication and allow clients to connect too.

The first cluster event was the failed SQL ip address followed by a failure to being sql service online followed by the same two failures on the original active node.

Is there something else about my configuration I need to check?  I don't get why it failed to fail-over until I rebooted the passive node.  I had rebooted that node the night before having ran windows updates.  Would that have something to do with it?

Thank you.